# Combining Buttons (actionCard) and a text prompt in a single sendActivity() of Botframework SDK V4 (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, botframework, prompt, adaptive-cards

[image]

I am trying to combine button + text + button (i.e,.cancel button) in the same adaptive card.

I tried to add "textBlock" after "Actions" block, it was not displaying it as expected!

```
{   

    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [

        {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Please select the buttons to proceed..",
              "wrap": true

        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Button1",
            "data": "Button1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Button2",
            "data": "Button2"
        },

      "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Please press Cancel to exit",
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Cancel",
            "data": "Cancel"
        }

        ]
```

Expected is: 
           Please select the buttons to proceed..
                    Button1
                    Button2
           Please press Cancel to exit

```
       Cancel (Button)
```

Actual result is: No particular error. Its not allowing to include "textBlock" after "Action" block.

Request anybody to help me on this issue.
Thank you.

Please find the expected format of Adaptive card image above in the hyperlink (enter image description here).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you use Containers and ActionSet. As it is, you can't place text blocks inside of the actions property, only the body. However, if you set up a container and place the first text block and button 1 and button 2 within it, you can then follow up it up with a second container with another text block and the cancel button.

This **does** require you to use version 1.2 as container items only take Actions placed in an ActionSet. If you are set on needing the second text block placed between the second and third button, then this is how you can do it, but be aware that v1.2 has not been implemented everywhere. You will want to specify the fallback to cover those cases.

You can also visit the Adaptive Card [Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to experiment more.

Hope of help!

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Please select the buttons to proceed...",
            "wrap": true,
            "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.Submit",
                            "title": "Button1",
                            "data": "Button1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Action.Submit",
                            "title": "Button2",
                            "data": "Button2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Please press Cancel to exit",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Cancel",
                    "data": "Cancel"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope of help!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But here, I want to add the textBlock also in between the buttons. I have also attached the image of card format required. Please check it.

Comment: @Punith, Apologies. I overlooked the second text block somehow.

Comment: @Punith, meant to add that I updated the solution, as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. ActionSet is not working in bot framework V4 version. I checked some of the Microsoft github links regarding the same, As per that, there is some bug in V4, that its not accepting ActionSet.Could you please suggest the workaround or any other solution to get the required result.